# how to delete the first file in a directory using fs action in oozie

Tags: oozie

How to delete the first subdirectory in a directory using Oozie HDFS action?

I have a directory named error_dir, now I process the first subdirectory (another action)
and then I want it to be removed so I can process others.

`<fs> 
      <delete path='${error_dir}/<blank>'/>
</fs>`

I don't know what to fill in that blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oozie FS action doesn't have such specialized functionality. You can implement this in [Java action](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/oozie/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.7_Java_Action) using HDFS API.